# Stuck on how to automate the scheduling of a Twilio Studio Flow, with Google Sheets and Schedule by Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, twilio, zapier

I am trying to automate (once a day) the running of a Twilio flow. The main thing I need Schedule to do is trigger a Twilio flow, sending information from a Google Sheet (Phone Number to send text to, text message text). The way it currently works is:

1. In Google Sheets I have Sheet1 which includes the columns: “Phone Number” and “Text Message Text”.
2. In Google Sheets, I also have an AppsScript that (when I click manually) will send the data to trigger a Twilio flow that sends a text to each “Phone Number” in the column their custom “Text Message Text”.
3. When the user respond to the text, I have custom code triggered in the Twilio flow that stores the output text in the same google sheet in the “Sheet2”

I can’t figure out how to make the scheduling part work in Zapier. I see how to connect Google Sheets + Twilio, and Schedule + Twilio, but I can’t figure out how to use Schedule to trigger sending info from a Google Sheet and kickstarting a Twilio flow. Any thoughts on how I could approach this? Or if there is a different set of tools I should think about using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get Zapier to trigger an action in Google Sheets that then runs the rest of the workflow.

Google Apps Script projects can be [published as web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), this gives them a URL that you can make requests to from an external source, like Zapier in this case. To do so, you need to define a `doPost(e)` function in your script that does some work and returns an `HTMLOutput` or `TextOutput` object. In your case, your `doPost(e)` function can call the function you have already created that sends the data to Twilio and then return an empty response.

Once you have hooked up the `doPost(e)` function, you can deploy the script as a Web App by clicking *Deploy -> New Deployment* and then selecting Web App as the deployment type. Once you've filled in the rest of the required data it will be deployed and you will have a URL. There's more on this process in [the Google Apps Script documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

You can then take that URL and use it as the destination for a [scheduled HTTP request in Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/schedule/integrations/webhook/2845/send-webhook-post-requests-on-a-daily-schedule).

Comment: This works! Almost. It works when I deploy the Apps Script allowing anybody to POST. But when I restrict it to myself, I can't POST from zapier. I'm guessing I need to pass some parameters with the POST to authenticate, but I can't figure out how?

Comment: Following up on this again - I realized that App Scripts has a built in scheduler, so I just ended up using that and skipping zapier.

Comment: Oh, amazing! Glad it's working for you now.